# Variable is Changed Before it Can Be Used (JavaScript ONLY)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just a highschooler trying to code a website, I ain't the best yet and therefore request any jQuery **NOT** be included int the solutions simply because I haven't learned it yet. However, I have run into a problem regarding eventListeners and the display property from CSS. Before I explain, the link to this project on GitHub is [here](https://github.com/junior-devleague/safe/tree/commentBox), it should be under the branch, commentBox. In short, I basically have a bunch of topics on the screen and when you click **"view comments"**, the topic is supposed to expand and an "add comments" textarea is supposed to appear. Here are three key things to know about how I made this code:

1. Once a topic is *expanded*, any clicks **inside** the topic do not close it
2. Any clicks **outside** an *expanded* topic closes the topic
3. While one topic is *expanded*, clicking "view comments" on another ***unexpanded*** topic will expand that topic and close the other

These parts of opening and closing the topics works, when the topic expands the comment box always shows up; however, the biggest error that has been occurring is when clicking on another "view comments" while another topic is expanded (number 3 listed above). The topic will open and the other topic closes but the comment box does not disappear. I believe this is because the variable *currentlyOpenComBox* changes to the newly opened comment box before the previous comment box can be set to, *display:none* because everything in the javascript is so dynamic and relies on what the user clicks.

Just Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbmmqbj7/1/) that includes the basic script or check out the GitHub project [here](https://github.com/junior-devleague/safe/tree/commentBox). The bulk of pure JS script you see below is the whole function of expanding and closing the divs. Please take a look here or at the jsfiddle.

```
var openCloseTopic = function(commentDiv){
  var topicDiv =  commentDiv.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  var currentlyOpenComBox;
  //diplays comment box at bottom of topic
  for(var i = 0; i < topicDiv.childNodes.length; i++){
    if(topicDiv.childNodes[i].tagName == "TEXTAREA"){
      currentlyOpenComBox = topicDiv.childNodes[i];
    }
  }

  //When user clicks on "view comments", expand div
  if(event.target == commentDiv){
    //this closes others div if you click on "view comments" and another div is already open
    var topicClass = document.getElementsByClassName("topic");
    for(var i = 0; i < topicClass.length; i++){
      if(topicClass[i].clientHeight == "400"){ //if any topic is already open close it
        //this keeps only one topic open at all times
        currentlyOpenComBox.style.display = "none";
        topicClass[i].style.height = "145px";
      }
    }

    topicDiv.style.height = "400px";
    currentlyOpenComBox.style.display = "block";
  }
  //When the user clicks anywhere outside of the topic, close it
  else{
    //checks to see if user is clicking inside topic div
    if(topicDiv.contains(event.target) && topicDiv.style.height == "400px"){
      topicDiv.style.height = "400px";
    }
    else{
      topicDiv.style.height = "145px";
      currentlyOpenComBox.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

//checks all clicks on window
var openTopic;
window.addEventListener("click", function(){
  openCloseTopic(openTopic);
},
false)

var commentClass = document.getElementsByClassName("comments");
for(var i = 0; i < commentClass.length; i++){
  commentClass[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    openCloseTopic(this);
    openTopic = this;
  }, 
  false);
}
```

Again, once in jsfiddle, click "view comments" on one div, then "view comments" again on another you'll find that the comment box does not disappear. Please no jQuery... Very much thanks in advance.

Comment: Try moving 'var currentlyOpenComBox;' outside of the 'openCloseTopic' function

Comment: Your variable `currentlyOpenComBox` points to a wrong node. You should really try using css classes for setting a height and hiding/showing elements instead of mixing logic and design in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are getting `currentlyOpenComBox` wrong, you are always getting the one that in div that you already clicked and changing the display of it. Not even working with old comment boxes. You have to define this `currentlyOpenComBox` as `global`, outside of function. At first try, that means when `currentlyOpenComBox`is undefined, define it at beginning of `openCloseTopic` function, after that just hold it until you give `display:none` for it, then define it to new box and give it `display:block`. Life-cycle goes like that.

```js
//SORT OVERLAY
function openOverlay(x) {
  document.getElementById("sortOverlay").style.border = "2px solid #838383";
  document.getElementById("sortOverlay").style.width = "250px";
  if (x === 1) {
    document.getElementById("sortOverlay").style.marginLeft = "0";
    var mostRecentHeight = document.getElementById("mostRecent").offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("sortOverlay").style.height = mostRecentHeight + "px";

  }

  if (x === 2) {
    document.getElementById("sortOverlay").style.marginLeft = "0";
    var allTopicsHeight = document.getElementById("allTopics").offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("sortOverlay").style.height = allTopicsHeight + "px";
  }
}

function closeOverlay() {
  document.getElementById("sortOverlay").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("sortOverlay").style.border = "0";
}
var currentlyOpenComBox;
var openCloseTopic = function(commentDiv) {
  var topicDiv = commentDiv.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
  
  //diplays comment box at bottom of topic
  if(currentlyOpenComBox==null)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < topicDiv.childNodes.length; i++) {
      if (topicDiv.childNodes[i].tagName == "TEXTAREA") {
        currentlyOpenComBox = topicDiv.childNodes[i];
      }
    }
  }

  //When user clicks on "view comments", expand div
  if (event.target == commentDiv) {
    //this closes others div if you click on "view comments" and another div is already open
    var topicClass = document.getElementsByClassName("topic");
    for (var i = 0; i < topicClass.length; i++) {
      if (topicClass[i].clientHeight == "400") {
        //this keeps only one topic open at all times
        currentlyOpenComBox.style.display = "none";
        topicClass[i].style.height = "145px";
      }
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < topicDiv.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (topicDiv.childNodes[i].tagName == "TEXTAREA") {
      currentlyOpenComBox = topicDiv.childNodes[i];
    }
  }
    
    topicDiv.style.height = "400px";
    currentlyOpenComBox.style.display = "block";
  }
  //When the user clicks anywhere outside of the topic, close it
  else {
    //checks to see if user is clicking inside topic div
    if (topicDiv.contains(event.target) && topicDiv.style.height == "400px") {
      topicDiv.style.height = "400px";
    } else {
      topicDiv.style.height = "145px";
      currentlyOpenComBox.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

//checks all clicks on window
var openTopic;
window.addEventListener("click", function() {
    openCloseTopic(openTopic);
  },
  false)

var commentClass = document.getElementsByClassName("comments");
//console.log(commentClass);
for (var i = 0; i < commentClass.length; i++) {
  commentClass[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      openCloseTopic(this);
      openTopic = this;
    },
    false);
}
```

```css
/*
font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
*/

.container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
}


/* Most Recent, left side of home page */

#mostRecent {
  display: inline-block;
}

#mostRecent h4 {
  display: none;
}

.topic {
  border: 2px solid #838383;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  /*padding-left: 60px;
 padding-top: 20px;
  height: 140px;*/
  height: 145px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #8D8D8D;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  transition: 0.2s;
  position: relative;
  /* this needs to be on parent to prevent commentBox from going outside div */
}

.topic:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.02, 1.02);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.02, 1.02);
  transform: scale(1.02, 1.02);
  transition: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.allInfo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.description {
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 77%;
  height: 90px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.titleBigger {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #838383;
}

.bottomInfo {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 77%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.date {
  display: block;
  /*margin-top: 37px;
 margin-left: 60px;*/
  width: 110px;
}

.comments {
  display: block;
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.comments:hover {
  color: #D0011B;
  transition: 0.1s;
}

.votes {
  width: 90px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.upArrow,
.downArrow {
  width: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.upArrow:hover,
.downArrow:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.93, 0.93);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.93, 0.93);
  transform: scale(0.93, 0.93);
  transition: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.commentBox {
  width: 97%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #C4C4C4;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  color: #838383;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 1.5%;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  /*gets rid of blue outline*/
}

.commentBox:focus {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border-color: #A0A0A0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Orbitron|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Home</title>

<body>
  </a>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Left Side with Most Recent -->
    <div id="mostRecent">
   <h1>MOST RECENT</h1>
   <h4><a href="all-topics.html ">VIEW ALL TOPICS</a></h4>
   <!-- List of Topics -->
   <div class="topic ">
     <div class="allInfo ">
     <div class="description ">
      <span class="titleBigger ">BETTER BATHROOMS</span>
      <br/><br />Bathrooms suck, better ones are needed. Toilets flush 40% of the time, you be able to wipe your butt 10% of the time if your luck enough to have a stall with toilet paper.
     </div>
     <div class="bottomInfo ">
      <div class="date ">added 4/10/2017</div>
      <div class="comments ">view comments <span>+</span></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Up & Down Arrows -->
    <div class="votes ">
     <div class="upArrow ">
      <img src="./images/up-arrow.png "/>
     </div>
     <div class="downArrow ">
      <img src="./images/down-arrow.png "/>
     </div>
    </div>
    <textarea type="text " class="commentBox " placeholder="Add comment... "></textarea>
   </div>

      <div class="topic ">
        <div class="allInfo ">
     <div class="description ">
      <span class="titleBigger ">POT HOLES IN THE PARKING LOT</span>
      <br/><br />Bathrooms suck need better ones
     </div>
     <div class="bottomInfo ">
      <div class="date ">added 4/10/2017</div>
      <div class="comments ">view comments <span>+</span></div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="votes ">
     <div class="upArrow ">
      <img src="./images/up-arrow.png "/>
     </div>
     <div class="downArrow ">
      <img src="./images/down-arrow.png "/>
     </div>
    </div>
    <textarea type="text " class="commentBox " placeholder="Add comment... "></textarea>
   </div>

   <div class="topic ">
     <div class="allInfo ">
     <div class="description ">
      <span class="titleBigger ">GRASS NEEDS TO BE MORE GREEN</span>
      <br/><br />Bathrooms suck need better ones
     </div>
     <div class="bottomInfo ">
      <div class="date ">added 4/10/2017</div>
      <div class="comments ">view comments <span>+</span></div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="votes ">
     <div class="upArrow ">
      <img src="./images/up-arrow.png "/>
     </div>
     <div class="downArrow ">
      <img src="./images/down-arrow.png "/>
     </div>
    </div>
    <textarea type="text " class="commentBox " placeholder="Add comment... "></textarea>
   </div>

   <div class="topic ">
     <div class="allInfo ">
     <div class="description ">
      <span class="titleBigger ">WATER FOUNTAINS ARE GROSS</span>
      <br/><br />Bathrooms suck ass need better ones
     </div>
     <div class="bottomInfo ">
      <div class="date ">added 4/10/2017</div>
      <div class="comments ">view comments <span>+</span></div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="votes ">
     <div class="upArrow ">
      <img src="./images/up-arrow.png "/>
     </div>
     <div class="downArrow ">
      <img src="./images/down-arrow.png "/>
     </div>
    </div>
    <textarea type="text " class="commentBox " placeholder="Add comment... "></textarea>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```